# Why I can't call a class method from the inside of this callback function? ERROR TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on an Angular application using TypeScript and I have the following problem.

Into a TypeScript class I have this method:

```
findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall(bid):Observable<Bid[]> {
  console.log("findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall() START")

  let data:Array<any> = null;
  return this.db.collection('bids',
      ref=> ref.where("wallId", "==", bid.wallId))
      .get()
      .pipe(
          map(snaps => {
             snaps.forEach(function(doc) {
             console.log("BLA: ", doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
             this.myClassMethod();

             return doc.data;
           });

              return null;
          })
          
          
      )
  }
```

So as you can see into the previous code I am calling a **forEach()** method on the **snaps** object.

This method take a callback funtion as paramether. Into this callback function I am trying to execute another method  (**myCassMethod()**) defined directly into my instance, in this way:

```
this.myClassMethod();
```

Doing in this way it isn't work because I am obtaining the following error messate into the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: this is undefined
    findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall notifications.service.ts:187
    node_modules vendor.js:159712
    node_modules vendor.js:145978
    node_modules vendor.js:145609
    node_modules vendor.js:145609
    node_modules vendor.js:145527
    node_modules vendor.js:145977
    node_modules vendor.js:159711
    findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall notifications.service.ts:184
    RxJS 4
    Angular 6
    RxJS 3
    Angular 16
    RxJS 4
    schedule Angular
    RxJS 4
    Angular 20
    node_modules vendor.js:157356
    node_modules NextJS
    node_modules vendor.js:149711
    node_modules vendor.js:149679
    Ur index.cjs.js:5711
    Us index.cjs.js:11891
    step tslib.es6.js:100
    verb tslib.es6.js:81
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:71
    Angular 13
```

It seems that form whthin this callback function it can't see the **this** as instance reference.

How can I solve this problem and correctly call my **myCassMethod()** method§?

Comment: `this` in JavaScript doesn't refer to a class of the instance, it usually refers to the instance itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: @Teemu yes I mean the instance itself...but from within this callback function I can't use it

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach(callback[, thisArg])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): _"If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach()`, it will be used as callback's `this` value. The `thisArg` value ultimately observable by callback is **determined according to [the usual rules for determining the `this` seen by a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)**."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing `snaps.forEach(function(doc) {` to `snaps.forEach( (doc) => {` but I'm not totally sure it will work.

Or by setting

```
findArtistBidsAppliedByCurrentWall(bid):Observable<Bid[]> {
   const that = this;
```

and using `that.` And this one is guarantee to work.

Comment: Trying using the that option but now it seems doesn't enter into the method...it give me no error but it is not executing the method code that print a log